# Is there is a way to call a object from a method?

Tags: c#, object, methods, call

New to C# want to know if there is a way to call a object from a method

Do I have to just keep typing

```
Console.WriteLine(James.name); Console.WrtieLine(James.age);
```

for each new object I make?

sorry if it is a simple question. :(

example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GVXV.png

namespace example
{

```
class Dog
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    
    public Dog(string _name, int _age)
    {
    name = _name;
    age = _age;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    Dog James = new Dog("James", 4);

    Dog Daniel = new Dog("Daniel", 2);
    }

    //I know from thispart it does not work but is there a way to make a similar result?
    
    status(James);
    status(Daniel);
}


public static void status(thisdog)
{
    Console.WriteLine(thisdog.name);
    Console.WrtieLine(thisdog.age);
}
```

Comment: It should be `void status(Dog thisdog)` - You've missed out the type

Comment: Look into how you can override `ToString` on `Dog`

Comment: Thank you so much guys I will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine, you just need to fix a few errors (Comments inline):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dog James = new Dog("James", 4);
        Dog Daniel = new Dog("Daniel", 2);

        status(James); // <-- This needs to be inside Main
        status(Daniel);
    }

     // This needs a type for the parameter and needs to be inside Program
    public static void status(Dog thisdog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(thisdog.name);
        Console.WriteLine(thisdog.age); // <-- fixed typo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer! (´・ω・`) Works like a charm now

Answer (score 2):

welcome on Stackoverflow.com! It's been awhile since C# but I'll give it a shot.

I've changed your code so it should work.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // 1.
        Dog james = new Dog("James", 4);
        Dog daniel = new Dog("Daniel", 2);
    
        // 2.
        status(james);
        status(daniel);
    }

    // 3.
    public static void status(Dog thisdog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(thisdog.name);
        Console.WrtieLine(thisdog.age);
    }
}
```

Lets go through it:

1. Naming: There are certain rules to follow. For example the upper and lower cases. For Classes and Methods you always should choose Uppercase like `Dog`. For properties and objects you should always use the Lowercase like `Dog james`. There are more rules for sure, but I can't remember.
2. Call the methods from within a method. As far as I remember this will work.
3. You forgot to add the class to the methods parameter.

I hope that helped a bit on your way. If there's anything wrong just let me know...as I said: It's been awhile.